# Is creating a wiki answer appropriate when multiple answers are complementary?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked the question: *[Does a "vegan leather" exist?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/71/does-a-vegan-leather-exist)*.

The answers provided were both fitting my expectations equally and I chose to accept an answer only by considering the post creation date (not a very persuasive factor).

In this case is it appropriate to up-vote each answer and to create a wiki answer that regroups the information?

The main benefit would be that the answer could be improved over the time if someone knows another alternative or if new techniques come out. Additionally, it doesn't give an advantage to one answer over the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, you shouldn't.

Your answer would only take more space and would technically be at the bottom of the page, where users and visitors will probably already see the previous answers. And also, copying other answers is usually discouraged unless the OP of that answer allows you to but there is a whole lot more to that subject. You can and should upvote both answers that helped you.

Unfortunately, if you choose one, it means that the selected answer was deemed the most helpful out of all other choices if present. If needed, don't accept any answer at all if both are equally useful.

Comment: As it would be a community answer, I don't think we can talk about copying. Moreover, a community answer that is up-voted doesn't grant reputation to anyone. Am I wrong? If I accept this answer, it would be at the top of the responses, no? (I'm not familiar with those meta cases)

Comment: @Niitaku Accepted answers that score > -3 are displayed first.

Comment: @Niitaku even if it is a CW answer it is still copied from others' posts and would "compete" with those posts, so that the authors are less likely to get due credit for their work

Comment: @Zanna Thx for this precision. I didn't thought about it and I agree with you. To prevent any doubt, my intent never was to stole work or reward from their authors, but to make an answer that contains all information. But I see your point and can't agree more.

Comment: @Niitaku your intent to improve the site in good faith was never in any doubt in my mind :)

Answer (score 3):

Voting is up to you. It seems a bit early in the site lifetime to be trying to pick canonical questions and answers though so I'd leave the wiki conversion alone for now. As it is you may still get more answers, maybe even one you feel is so good you change your accepted answer.

If your question is asked again and again that's the sort of thing that indicates that a canonical wiki question/answer might be useful.